# Space button click puts Auto suggestion to the EditText Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

Please, help me to solve this strange problem. I try to implement EditText, where user can add links to user profiles, hashtags and so on. I have OnTextChanged method where I get current text from EditText, process it and put it to EditText backward.

```
@OnTextChanged(R.id.share_article_say_something)
    public void onTextChanged() {
        if (mIsTextChangedManually) {
            mIsTextChangedManually = false;
            return;
        }
        mIsTextChangedManually = true;
        SpannableStringBuilder builder = mCommentsSpannable.format(mSaySomethingTv.getText().toString());
        mSaySomethingTv.setTextKeepState(builder);
    }
```

EditText looks like that

```
<com.slangwho.views.SWEditText
            android:id="@+id/share_article_say_something"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/my_friend_pressed_color"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textSize="@dimen/splash_screen_button_text_sp"
            android:hint="@string/say_something"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/ed_cursor_drawable_black"
            app:fontName="ProximaNova-Regular"/>
```

This EditText extends regular EditText just to add 1 additional parameter, which is fontName.

When I type some text I receive wrong suggestions(cursor is after single standing "s")
[image]

When I typing "Space", I receive:(The First suggestion adds after single standing "s")
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that it was a problem with Samsung Swipe Keyboard. When I set text to the edit text using EditText.setText() or EditText.setTextKeepState() the keyboard suggestions behave strange. The solution was not to set text to the EditText, but set TextWatcher to the EditText and transform Editable in the method afterTextChanged(Editable s).

```
public class SocialTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    CommentsSpannable mCommentSpannable;

    public SocialTextWatcher(CommentsSpannable commentsSpannable) {
        mCommentSpannable = commentsSpannable;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }


    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        mCommentSpannable.formatEditable(s);
    }
}
```